# Hangouts Crashes on Start can't seem to write to com.google.android.talk

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-hangouts

I recently updated to a more recent version of the 12.1 nightlies of Cyanogenmod on my Nexus 5. Everything Google related seems to work except Hangouts. When I open hangouts it crashes immediately. The logs seem to show an inability to write to `data/data/com.google.android.talk` and an inability to read the SQLite databases within (some exploration in the shell reveals that the folder is empty).

What I've tried:

1. Wiping the caches
2. Installing new versions of Gapps
3. Wiping data and cache for Hangouts
4. Installing Hangouts Dialer
5. `chmod 757` on that folder

I see that just about every data folder has a unique owner and group, could hangouts have somehow gotten mixed up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I booted to recovery, wiped the caches, flashed a version of gapps for 4.4, then flashed the latest version of gapps then won.